# How to put a PDF figure on top of another one

Tags: floats, pdf

I have two PDF figures (charts) in a LaTeX document. As one of them is really simple, and I have some document space constraints, I was thinking of putting it in the upper right corner of the second chart.

I could do this using some image editing tool.
But can I do it directly in LaTeX (avoiding the need to create a single merged PDF)?

Comment: You could simply use a `picture` environment and place both images with `\put`.

Comment: @Stephan: would you mind giving an example, as I can't find how to include `figure` (environments) in a `picture` environment? For example, this link (http://www.ursoswald.ch/LaTeXGraphics/picture/picture.html) doesn't talk about it, as doesn't the picture package documentation.

Comment: You don't need to use the `figure` environment to use `\includegraphics`. Place the whole `picture` environment in a single `figure` environment if you want it to float.

Comment: `\includegraphics[height=4cm]{chart1.pdf}\llap{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{chart2.pdf}}}`. You might have to play a bit with the numbers, height of chart2 + raise = height of chart1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Typesetting material over each other is relatively easy without any extra packages by exploiting the `\llap` and `\rlap` TeX commands. These basically typeset some material from the current position to the left, respectively right, regardless what and without changing the current position.

As graphics included by `\includegraphics` are aligned at the bottom, one additionally can use `\raisebox` to lift the second graphics in y direction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[3]
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image-a}%
    \llap{\raisebox{3cm}{%  move next graphics to top right corner
      \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}%
    }}
    \caption{My overlay figure.}
  \end{figure}  

  \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one does not want to scale the first figure to a specific height, but to something like `\columnwidth`, it is also possible to measure the resulting height. There are many ways to do this (which basically all results in: "box it" + "measure it") In the following, I simply use the functionality provided by the `calc` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}       % for height measuring

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[3]
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    % first measure it's height (store in \dimen0), then actually include the graphics
    \settototalheight{\dimen0}{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}%
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \llap{\raisebox{\dimen0-3cm}{%  move next graphics to top right corner
      \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}%
    }}
    \caption{My overlay figure.}
  \end{figure}  

  \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very clear example. Unfortunately, seems like I do have to specify the height of the first figure (like you did with `height=6cm`), as when using `width=\columnwidth` instead, the positioning gets messed up.

Comment: @Rabarberski: It's possible to automatically determine the height. See updated answer.

Comment: Where are the background lines in your last image?

Comment: @Forgiver: In the PDF they are still there, just have been "optimized" away in the PDF->GIF conversion for the screenshot.

Comment: I see. I thought you intentionally removed it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a generic solution. With a trivial edit you will get what you want. Please TeXing it with either `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newbox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{god}}

\def\Rows{5}
\def\Columns{5}

\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\Columns\relax,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\Rows\relax,
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{figure}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](\dimexpr\wd\IBox+3\psxunit\relax,\ht\IBox)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \rput[tr](8,5){\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{The Gods must be crazy.}%
\label{fig:}%
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{document}
```

The image is taken from [The Gods must be crazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gods_must_be_crazyposter.jpg).

---

Hopefully it is the last edit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newbox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}}

\def\Rows{5}
\def\Columns{5}

\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\Columns\relax,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\Rows\relax,
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{figure}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \rput[tr](\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox){\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{Is the answer of this question ``No''?}%
\label{fig:}%
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is great, but I missed the ability to move the smaller image (which in my case is a plot legend) horizontally as well as vertically. I'd also rather have the smaller image's size and coordinates defined in terms of the bigger one. So after a bit of tinkering I came up with the following macro:

```
\newlength{\imagew}
\newlength{\imageh}
\newlength{\legendw}
\newlength{\legendh}
\newlength{\legendx}
\newlength{\legendy}
\newcommand{\graphicswithlegend}[6]{
  \setlength{\imagew}{#1}
  \settoheight{\imageh}{\includegraphics[width=\imagew]{#2}}

  \setlength{\legendw}{#3\imagew}
  \settoheight{\legendh}{\includegraphics[width=\legendw]{#4}}

  \setlength{\legendx}{\imagew}
  \addtolength{\legendx}{-\legendw}
  \addtolength{\legendx}{-#5\imagew}

  \setlength{\legendy}{\imageh}
  \addtolength{\legendy}{-\legendh}
  \addtolength{\legendy}{-#6\imageh}

  \includegraphics[width=\imagew]{#2}%
  \llap{
    \hspace{-\the\legendx}
    \raisebox{\legendy}{\includegraphics[width=\legendw]{#4}}
    \hspace{\the\legendx}
  }
}
```

The macro above takes six arguments:

- The larger image's width and path;
- The smaller image's width and path;
- The smaller image's horizontal and vertical displacements relative to the larger image's top-left corner.

See below for an example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\imagew}
\newlength{\imageh}
\newlength{\legendw}
\newlength{\legendh}
\newlength{\legendx}
\newlength{\legendy}
\newcommand{\graphicswithlegend}[6]{
  \setlength{\imagew}{#1}
  \settoheight{\imageh}{\includegraphics[width=\imagew]{#2}}

  \setlength{\legendw}{#3\imagew}
  \settoheight{\legendh}{\includegraphics[width=\legendw]{#4}}

  \setlength{\legendx}{\imagew}
  \addtolength{\legendx}{-\legendw}
  \addtolength{\legendx}{-#5\imagew}

  \setlength{\legendy}{\imageh}
  \addtolength{\legendy}{-\legendh}
  \addtolength{\legendy}{-#6\imageh}

  \includegraphics[width=\imagew]{#2}%
  \llap{
    \hspace{-\the\legendx}
    \raisebox{\legendy}{\includegraphics[width=\legendw]{#4}}
    \hspace{\the\legendx}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[3]
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \graphicswithlegend{\columnwidth}{example-image-a}
                       {0.5}{example-image-b}{0.52}{0.0}
    \caption{My overlay figure.}
  \end{figure}

  \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image: compiled Latex document]