# How to discard an area of a pdf page using pdfpages?

Tags: pdfpages, crop, clip

I'm writing a text tha includes some pdf pages from external document. [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6XiD7MJaw4mblA1Qi13VzgzeFE/view) specific page is driving me crazy. I'd like to include it without this specific area:

[image]

Anyone knows how to do this using `pdfpages` package or even other packages/commands?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[%
left=3.00cm,
right=2.00cm,
top=3.00cm,
bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{qqqqq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe overlay a white box like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95280

Comment: There may be a pdfpages-based answer, but for a single instance of this, I'd suggest any PDF editor where you can draw a white rectangle over the unwanted material.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can place the image (yes, the page is just an image) on a blank page using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) and [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). Then you can overlay a `white` rectangular `\rule` to fill in over the area you don't want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,eso-pic,graphicx,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\clearpage

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{qqqqq}}%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth][r]
      {\raisebox{-\height}{\color{white}\rule{.25\paperwidth}{.75\paperheight}}}%
  }%
}
\mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

Note though that the text might still be selectable within the PDF. However, this might not be an issue of you're dealing with printed media. If you truly want the content removed, you'll have to crop it out with external software, or insert the image in cropped versions (top and bottom, with the top having it's right side cropped to remove the unnecessary content).