# Put a full image before some chapters

Tags: graphics, chapters, memoir, blank-page, xcoffins

I want to put some full page images in substitution of blank pages before chapters.
I know exactly where to put them and what image to put.
For example: at page 74 (a left page), before chapter 12 which starts at page 75 (a right page) there's a blank page. I want to substitute it with a figure (using \includepdf) without any change in other pages (before and after). There's a simple and elegant way? I'm using memoir class. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: `\clearpage\includepdf{zzz}\chapter{Something}` should work

Comment: Is the image a full-size page PDF? Or just a regular image (say, JPG)?

Comment: it is a full pdf of perfect dimensions.

Comment: David, thank you but it seems to put two extrapages. I use \part{Tecnologia}\clearpage\includepdf[noautoscale, templatesize={226mm}{290mm}]{\folderimmagini FULL-3.pdf}
\chapter{Storia del sonoro per l'audiovisivo} and the result is a page dedicated to part "Tecnologia", a blank page (I don't want), the picture, another blank page (I don't want), and the first page of the chapter "Storia del sonoro per l'audiovisivo".

Comment: @Simone Corelli I updated the answer to stay within `memoir`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memoir` class provides several means of moving onwards to another page. In particular for your case:

```
\movetoevenpage[stuff] 
\cleartoevenpage[stuff]
```

The `\movetoevenpage` stops the current page and starts typesetting on the next even numbered page. `\cleartoevenpage` flushes out all floats before going to the next even page. In both cases `stuff`, if present, is put on the skipped page (if there is one).
So, you could do something along the lines of:

```
... last line of the previous chapter.
\cleartoevenpage[\includepdf...]
\chapter{Next chapter}
...
```

For preventing a blank page after a `\part` use @SimonDispa's code for redefining `\partpageend`

**EDIT**

I should have said:

```
\movetoevenpage{stuff}
\cleartoevenpage{stuff}
```

As noted by @SimoneCorelli.

**EDIT 2**

Ignore the above, the macros are:

```
\movetoevepage[stuff]
\cleartoevenpage[stuff]
```

where `stuff` is put on the skipped blank page (if there is one). Calling
`\movetoevenpage{stuff}`
puts `stuff` on the page *after* the skipped blank page.

Comment: Peter, thanks! I feel we are on the right path. But at the moment instead of a picture I see some characters (on the correct page): "ImmaginiCMYK/FULL(p090).pdf]". The command is \cleartoevenpage[\includepdf[pages=1, noautoscale, templatesize={226mm}{290mm}]{\folderimmagini FULL(p090).pdf}]
\chapter{Linguaggi}, where \folderimmagini is a command that substitute foldername in all the LaTeX document. Any ideas?

Comment: I've found the culprit! brackets! Not [ ], but { }. GREAT!

Comment: Now it's ok before chapter, after another chapter, but it put 2 blank pages if used after a \part. I've put the code suggested by @SimonDispa that redefine \partpageend. Perhaps I have to add something more... Can you kindly tell me exactly what part of the Dispa's code I need to put in the preamble? Thanks!

Comment: @SimoneCorelli As I said, his code for `\makatletter\renewcommand*\partpageend{...}\makeatother`.

Comment: I did it but no change

Comment: Please see the updated answer

Comment: I needed to redefine also `\afterpartskip` to make it work.

Comment: NOw it seems perfect!!! I'll put every pdf and I'm sure it will look amazing. Great job Simon and Peter! Thanks from Italy

Comment: @SimoneCorelli Please see my edited answer. I don't know what you have done but the proper optional argument to `\move...` is in square brackets `[]` not braces `{}`. Perhaps you would show us what you finally did.

Comment: @PeterWilson Thank you! Yes, I noticed the error in braces and having corrected them I've been able to solve my problem completely. So... great job! Thanks to all. I hope it will become useful for many other users.

Answer (score 3):

The answer needs two "parts":

(1) Prevent `\part` in `memoir` to issue a `\newpage` after filling the part page. This is done redefining  `\partpageend` by commenting a line. (marked with `<<<<<<<<<<<`)

(2) I usually  use  `xcoffins` to put material in the page in the place I want. First the figure or the pdf or text, etc. is put into the special boxes, defined by the package, and then attached (only one in this case) to another box that serves has frame, with X and Y offsets. `(X offset, Y offset)` in the command `\Join...`

The frame is then typeset as a text object in the current insertion point, as if it where the first letter of a text in the page. So we need to displace it to its proper place, the top left corner for example, using the margins dimensions  or arbitrary lengths to put it where we want.

I made 3 examples in the document: at the end of a chapter that ends in a even page, so there is a blank odd page before the next chapter; inserting a dummy figure after `\part`; and inserting a pdf page after `\part`. (The cover of a manual)

Over time, I found that `xcoffins` was superior to other alternatives. It is easy to learn, just a few commands, and it emulates a graphic design program, placing the material in boxes and then attaching the boxes and adding offsets using their relative positions. This is a very simple case, but you might well want put more things over the background image: a text, a table or another figure. See for example

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573206/161015

[image: a]

[image: c]

This is the code.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text    
\RequirePackage{calc} % easier calculations 
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\NewCoffin\Framex
\NewCoffin\FigA

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\partpageend}{\afterpartskip
    \ifm@mnopartnewpage
    \else
    \if@twoside
    \if@openright
    \null
    \thispagestyle{afterpart}%
%   \newpage %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
    \fi}
\makeatother

\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Introduction}
\kant[1-12]
%%%%%********************************* image end of chapter
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\FigA{\includegraphics[width=\stockwidth, height=\stockheight]{example-image-a}}
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[l,t]\FigA[l,t](-\foremargin,\uppermargin+12pt) % XY offset
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\Framex
%****************************************************************

\part{Tecnologia I}
%%%%%*****************************************  image after part
\thispagestyle{empty}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Framex{}  %clear the frame
\SetHorizontalCoffin\FigA{\includegraphics[width=\stockwidth, height=\stockheight]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[l,t]\FigA[l,t](-\foremargin,\uppermargin+24pt)  % XY offset
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\Framex
%****************************************************************
\chapter{Storia del sonoro per l'audiovisivo} 
\kant[30-35]

\part{Tecnologia II}
%%%************************************************ pdf (cover) after part
\thispagestyle{empty}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Framex{} %clear the frame
\SetHorizontalCoffin\FigA{\includegraphics[width=\stockwidth, height=\stockheight]{pgfmanual.pdf}}
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[l,t]\FigA[l,t](-\foremargin,\uppermargin+24pt)  % XY offset
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\Framex
%***********************************

\chapter{Final} 
    \kant[8-12]
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

Following Peter Wilson's suggestion it is possible to have  everything inside  memoir's world.

It is needed to remove another `\newpage`, now from `\afterpartskip` to prevent memoir from stubbornly keep adding a blank page after `\part`

The code it is simpler, although I have to reach the page 335 of the manual. Excellent manual, by the way!

[image: xx]

[image: zz]

```
%%%%%%% UPDATED CODE 
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside,openright]{memoir}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text        
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%%%%% *************************  changes to memoir
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\partpageend}{%
    \afterpartskip
    \ifm@mnopartnewpage
    \else
    \if@twoside
    \if@openright
    \null
    \thispagestyle{afterpart}%
%   \newpage %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
    \fi
}

\makeatother

\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vfil%
%   \newpage %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}

%%%%% ************************* 

\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Introduction}
\kant[1-12]

\part{Tecnologia I}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleartoevenpage{\includegraphics[width=0.8\stockwidth, height=0.8\stockheight]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
    
\chapter{Storia del sonoro per l'audiovisivo} 
\kant[30-35]

\part{Tecnologia II}
\cleartoevenpage{\includepdf[noautoscale,height=\stockheight]{pgfmanual.pdf}}

\chapter{Final} 
    \kant[8-10] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to thank you very much and I'm sure this can be helpful for many users. But for me is too much complicate and I hoped for a more simple solution. At the moment I use Apple Preview to edit pdf pages dragging the thumbnails between two docs. It is ok but not elegant... and it is slow with big files, but it works. Thanks again