# Image on left hand page in twoside document

Tags: graphics, koma-script, double-sided

I want to place an image on a new left hand page in a twoside document which I accomplished (see MWE). Is there a more elegant or simpler way to achieve what I did with the `newcommand` which seems a bit clunky to me?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\cleardoubleevenpage

\begin{figure}{H}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Testbild.jpeg}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\newcommand{\lhfigure}[2]{%
    \cleardoubleevenpage
    \begin{figure}{H}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}
    \end{figure}}

\lhfigure{\textwidth}{Testbild.jpeg}

\lipsum[1-2]


\end{document}
```

Comment: This question asks the same thing, although not for `scrreport`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578486

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will try to look into it whether I can adapt it for my needs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `newcommand` to the following to get the currently desired result:

```
\newcommand{\tempfig}[4][0.75]{% Hilfsbefehl
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[page=#2,scale=#1]{#3}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{\caption{#4}}
\end{figure}}

% Skript auf neuer geraden Seiten
\newcommand{\lhfigure}[4][0.75]{% praktisch für Vorlesungsmitschriften (Skript auf linker Seite, Notizen darunter und auf rechter Seite)
    \cleardoubleevenpage
    \tempfig[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}

% Skript auf neuer ungeraden Seiten
\newcommand{\rhfigure}[4][0.75]{% alternative zur "Skript auf neuer geraden Seite"
    \cleardoubleoddpage
    \tempfig[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}
```

Here is my `TIKZ`-based solution (based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/244141)):

```
% Skript auf neuer geraden Seite mit TIKZ
\newcommand{\lhtikz}[4]{% praktisch für Vorlesungsmitschriften (Skript auf linker Seite, Notizen darunter und auf rechter Seite)
    \cleardoubleevenpage
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {        \includegraphics[page=#1,width=\textwidth]{#2}};
            \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
                #4;
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{\caption{#3}}
    \end{figure}}

\newcommand{\rectangle}[2]{% Rechteckt in TIKZ zeichnen
    \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (#1) rectangle (#2)}

\newcommand{\tikzcircled}[2]{% Kreis mit Text in TIKZ zeichnen
        \node[red, shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) at (#2) {#1}}
```

Purpose: I want to use this for notes on lectures I am attending