# How to adjust the floating position of one figure above the other?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I'd like to have one figure floating over another in a subfigure environment. Following the answers already offered here ([How to put a PDF figure on top of another one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62071/how-to-put-a-pdf-figure-on-top-of-another-one)), I managed to place one over the other. However, I found no clue how I could fine adjust the position of a second figure, relative or absolute position. Let's say , I rather like the `Legend` figure to be positioned 1cm from the right and bottom of the border of Figure 1. How could I set that?

Here is my figure structure:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Figure 1}{
  \includegraphics[width=0.92\linewidth]{../Figure1.pdf}}
\llap{\raisebox{20mm}{\hspace{1cm}\includegraphics[height=35mm]{../Legend.pdf}}}
  \par\medskip
\subcaptionbox{Figure 2}{
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{../Figure2.jpg}
  }\medskip
\subcaptionbox{Figure 3}{
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{../Figure3.jpg}
  }
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should achieve your goal. Note the use of [`%` in strategic spots to avoid spurious spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Figure 1}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.92\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{1cm}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}\hspace{1cm}}

  \medskip

  \subcaptionbox{Figure 2}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
  }\quad
  \subcaptionbox{Figure 3}{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}%
  }
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Your use of `\medskip` in horizontal mode actually puts the space between the two lower images and the `\caption`. I've changed that to `\quad`.

For completeness, I've used `\makebox[0pt][r]` instead of `\llap` (they achieve the same goal though).

Comment: I am sorry, but is there any difference between using `subfigure` environment and `\subcaptionbox`?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: The differences are minimal and may depend on your usage. [This paste](https://pastebin.com/U6zUrKFh) shows the difference when compiling similar content for a `subfigure` and a `\subcaptionbox`. The former doesn't align the first line of the sub-caption with one another, while the second does.

Comment: The difference is really noticeable in this case. Thanks for your explanation.